# Masturbating before Azan and the Azan break out

Tags: sawm, ramadan

Someone asked me this what is the answer should I give
Does it break if someone start masturbating before suhur Azan and the suhur Azan break out? And he ejaculates during the Azan

Comment: Brother, what?! Since you mention suhur specifically, so I infer this is in context of fasting. My guy masturbating, intercourse with wife, etc. once suhur azaan happens, all BREAK your fast, as far as I know. You can't be doing it. Simple as that.